# How to get to the wso2 microintegrator dashboard page by going to https://127.0.0.1:9743/login

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I need some help. I have racked my brain to find a solution. I cannot understand why I cannot get to the wso2 microintegrator dashboard page with the following credentials: login - admin; password - admin. In the documentation, these credentials are the default, but I get "Login faild". Where in the configuration can I see these credentials or how can I change them.

Thank you all in advance for your participation.

This is config of deployment.toml /mi-dashboard/conf :

```
[server_config]
port = 9743

[heartbeat_config]
pool_size = 15

[mi_user_store]
username = "admin"
password = "admin"

[keystore]
file_name = "conf/security/dashboard.jks"
password = "wso2carbon"
key_password = "wso2carbon"`
```

Log from wso2carbon :

```
[2022-09-30 11:46:25,493]  INFO {org.wso2.ei.dashboard.bootstrap.Bootstrap} - WSO2 Micro Integration Monitoring Dashboard started.
[2022-09-30 11:46:25,493]  INFO {org.wso2.ei.dashboard.bootstrap.Bootstrap} - Login to Micro Integrator Dashboard : 'https://DESKTOP-K718:9743/login'
[2022-09-30 11:46:28,337] ERROR {org.wso2.ei.dashboard.core.rest.delegates.auth.LoginDelegate} - No running micro integrator instances found. Please start a server and login.
[2022-09-30 11:46:28,586]  INFO {org.wso2.ei.dashboard.core.rest.delegates.heartbeat.HeartBeatDelegate} - New node 436a23b0-0f08-4653-a82d-318c8f25117b in group : default is registered. Inserting heartbeat information
[2022-09-30 11:46:29,055]  INFO {org.wso2.ei.dashboard.micro.integrator.MiArtifactsManager} - Fetching artifacts from node 436a23b0-0f08-4653-a82d-318c8f25117b in group default
[2022-09-30 11:46:37,282] ERROR {org.wso2.ei.dashboard.core.rest.delegates.auth.LoginDelegate} - Error logging into dashboard server java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at org.wso2.ei.dashboard.core.rest.delegates.auth.LoginDelegate.getTokenFromMI(LoginDelegate.java:65)
    at org.wso2.ei.dashboard.core.rest.delegates.auth.LoginDelegate.authenticateUser(LoginDelegate.java:43)
    at org.wso2.ei.dashboard.core.rest.api.LoginApi.receiveLogin(LoginApi.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1443)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1612)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What is the micro integrator you are testing? Do you see any errors in the logs?

Comment: Micro integrator of integration studio 8.0.0. In log wso2error in WSO2-Integration-Studio-8.0.0-win32-x86_64\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\repository\logs i see next "/Login is accessible only when JWT based auth handler is engaged" and in wso2carbon i see log "INFO {org.wso2.micro.integrator.management.apis.security.handler.AuthenticationHandlerAdapter} - User admin logged in successfully". I tried to add config [management_api.jwt_token_security_handler]
enable = false and [management_api.jwt_token_security_handler]
enable = true in deployment.toml but nothing changes.

Comment: Can you please share the carbon logs in `WSO2-Integration-Studio-8.0.0-win32-x86_64\IntegrationStudio\mi-dashboard\logs` as well?

Comment: I added to main field

Comment: Evgeniy, What you have added is the micro integrator log. There is a log for the dashboard as well in `WSO2-Integration-Studio-8.0.0-win32-x86_64\IntegrationStudio\mi-dashboard\logs`. Could you please add it as well?

Comment: I apologize for my lack of attention. I corrected the main question field .